# Restricting jQuery slideToggle from working on more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have a block of repeating images, each with a caption underneath. I am using slideToggle to show and hide the caption for each image when the image is clicked.

```
 $('.imageholder').click(function() {
 $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");

 });
```

A working fiddle showing my method is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/euphemus/km6zm1y6/6/).

This works as it should but I want to prevent multiple captions from being visible simultaneously. As a user clicks an image, any open captions should close. In my example, you will see it is possible to open all captions. This is what I want to prevent.

Would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like this?

```
$('.imageholder').click(function() {
     $('.description').slideUp();
     $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try hiding the other visible elements:

```
$('.imageholder').click(function() {
  $('.description:visible').not($(this).next()).slideToggle("fast");
  $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`slideUp()` all descriptions that aren't the current one, then `slideToggle()` the current one.

```
$('.imageholder').click(function() {
  var $desc = $(this).next();
  $('.description').not($desc).slideUp('fast');
  $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```